# Why is my array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am attempting to make a program that allows two player checkers. The teacher said it must use a 2d array but when it runs it says the array is out of bounds.

```
int[][] pieceStatus[3][7];
```

it is a four by eight because half of the squares on the chessboard (in this case black) are not used.

```
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i<=7; i++) 
    {
        if(i<3)
        {
            pieceStatus[j][i]=1;
        }
        if(i>2&&i<5)
        {
            pieceStatus[j][i]=0;
        }
        if(i>4)
        {
            pieceStatus[j][i]=2;
        }
        if(i==7&&j<=3)
        {
            i=0;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Zero means that there is no piece there.

Comment: Don't use [magic numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) for this sort of thing. Arrays have a length property that will help you prevent running into this type of error.

Comment: The array should be 4×8, not 3×7. Array *indices* start at zero, and when you loop you'll get indices from 0-3 or 0-7. The *dimensions* should not be minus-one.

Comment: You say its 4x8 but the question shows 3x7.

Comment: Read the error message. It doesn't say what it says in your title.